Heuristics and IDA* for an F2L solver not working and I don't know why
I have generated a simple heuristics database for an F2L solver for a Rubik's cube. I represent the state in a way that I need 2 heuristic databases. One is for the pair corner and the other is for the 5 edges(4 corner edges and 1 corresponding pair edge).
I have generated the heuristics for a max depth of 6 for testing purposes.
The corner heuristic database contains 24 lines (which is expected) and the edge database contains around 200k lines of states (which is less than expected, but for testing purposes fine enough, I calculated it to be around 3 million).
Here is an example of the corner database:
    "((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 3, 2), (0, 0, 0))": 0,
    "((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (2, 3, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))": 1,
    "((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 3, 2))": 1,
    "((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (3, 0, 2), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))": 1,
    "((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (2, 3, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))": 1,
    "((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 2, 3), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))": 1,
    "((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (3, 2, 0))": 1,

Here is an example of the edge database:
    "((0, 4), (0, 0), (0, 3), (0, 2), (0, 0), (0, 1), (3, 2), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0))": 1,
    "((0, 4), (0, 1), (2, 3), (0, 2), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 3), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0))": 1,
    "((0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 4), (0, 3), (0, 0), (0, 0), (3, 2), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0))": 1,
    "((0, 4), (0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 2), (0, 0), (0, 0), (3, 2), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0))": 1,
    "((0, 4), (0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 0), (3, 2), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0))": 1,
    "((0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 2), (4, 0), (0, 0), (3, 2), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0))": 1,
    "((0, 4), (0, 0), (0, 3), (0, 2), (0, 1), (0, 0), (3, 2), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0))": 1,
    "((0, 4), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 0), (0, 0), (3, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (2, 3), (0, 0))": 1,

I use JSON to save the database.
The order how the edges and corners are in the tuple show the location of each edge and corner on the cube, and the order the colors are correspond to their orientation.
The issue I have is that when I run my python IDA* script it works just fine for solutions that require one move to solve, but as soon as the depth gets bigger than 2 it just runs and never stops.
Here is the code that I already have:
from random import choice
from rubiks_cube import Cube
import json
import copy

ACTIONS = ["L", "R", "U", "D", "F", "B", "L'", "R'", "U'", "D'", "F'", "B'", "L2", "R2", "U2", "D2", "F2", "B2"]

class IDA_star(object):
    def __init__(self, heuristicEdge, heuristicCorner, max_depth = 20):
 
        self.max_depth = max_depth
        self.threshold = max_depth
        self.min_threshold = None
        self.heuristicEdge = heuristicEdge
        self.heuristicCorner = heuristicCorner
        self.moves = []

    def run(self, cube):
     
        while True:
            status = self.search(cube, 1)
            if status: return self.moves
            self.moves = []
            self.threshold = self.min_threshold
        return []

    def search(self, cube, g_score):
        cube_copy = copy.deepcopy(cube)

        edge_state = get_edge_state(cube_copy)
        corner_state = get_corner_state(cube_copy)
        if is_goal_state(corner_state, edge_state):
            return True
        elif len(self.moves) >= self.threshold:
            return False
        min_val = float('inf')
        best_action = None

        for a in ACTIONS:
            cube_copy.do_moves(a)

            edge_state = get_edge_state(cube_copy)
            corner_state = get_corner_state(cube_copy)

            if is_goal_state(corner_state, edge_state):
                self.moves.append(a)
                return True


            h_score_edge = self.heuristicEdge[str(edge_state)] if str(edge_state) in self.heuristicEdge else self.max_depth
            h_score_corner = self.heuristicCorner[str(corner_state)] if str(corner_state) in self.heuristicCorner else self.max_depth

            h_score = h_score_edge + h_score_corner

            f_score = g_score + h_score

            if f_score < min_val:
                min_val = f_score
                best_action = [(cube_copy, a)]
            elif f_score == min_val:
                if best_action is None:
                    best_action = [(cube_copy, a)]
                else:
                    best_action.append((cube_copy, a))
        if best_action is not None:
            if self.min_threshold is None or min_val < self.min_threshold:
                self.min_threshold = min_val

            next_action = choice(best_action)

            self.moves.append(next_action[1])
            status = self.search(next_action[0], g_score + min_val)
            if status: return status
        return False

goal_corner_state = ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 3, 2), (0, 0, 0))
goal_edge_state = ((0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (2, 3), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 1), (0, 4))

def is_goal_state(corner_state, edge_state):
    return corner_state == goal_corner_state and edge_state == goal_edge_state

def get_corner_and_edge_state(cube):
    return get_corner_state(cube), get_edge_state(cube)

def get_edge_state(cube):
    edges = cube.get_edges()
    state = [[0, 0] for _ in range(12)]
    for i, edge in enumerate(edges):
        if set(edge) in [{0, 2}, {0, 3}, {2, 3}, {0, 4}, {0, 1}]:
            state[i] = list(edge)
    return tuple(tuple(edge) for edge in state)

def get_corner_state(cube):
    corners = cube.get_corners()
    state = [[0,0,0] for _ in range(8)]
    for i, corner in enumerate(corners):
        if set(corner) == {0, 2, 3}:
            state[i] = list(corner)  # Preserve the order of colors
            break
    return tuple(tuple(corner) for corner in state)  # Make it hashable


MAX_MOVES = 5

HEURISTIC_FILE_EDGE = '/heuristic_f2l_one_pair_edge.json'
HEURISTIC_FILE_CORNER = '/heuristic_f2l_one_pair_safe.json'

with open(HEURISTIC_FILE_EDGE, 'r') as f:
    heuristicEdge = json.load(f)

with open(HEURISTIC_FILE_CORNER, 'r') as f:
    heuristicCorner = json.load(f)

cube = Cube(0)
cube.do_algorithm("z2 L' U' L")

solver = IDA_star(heuristicEdge, heuristicCorner)
moves = solver.run(Cube(0))
print(moves)

